# RAMdisk without previous installation with user privileges (portable mode) on windows

Tags: portable-applications, ramdisk, limited-user

Is there a way to use some kind of RAMdisk without previous installation of RAMdisk software of any kind with user privileges on system windows (XP, Vista or 7 at least)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out it is not possible. Windows kernel simply need administrator privileges to install modul/driver for RAMdisk.